# How to limit image width without stretching the image

Tags: css, image, width

I am trying to write an `img` tag for images that are different sizes (in the image file).  For images that are larger than the container, I want to scale the images down to `width: 100%`.  However, I down want the images that are smaller than the container to scale up; I want them to be rendered in their natural size when viewed in a larger window.

Here’s what I’ve tried:

- `<img src='image.jpg' alt='image'>` causes the images that are larger
  than the container to spill out.
- `<img src='image.jpg' alt='image' style='width:100%;'>` scales down
  the images that are larger than the container (GOOD), but scales up
  the images that are smaller than the container (BAD).
- In Chrome, `<img src='image.jpg' alt='image' style='max-width:100%;'>`
  scales down the images that are larger than the container (GOOD) and 
  doesn’t scale the images that are smaller than the container (GOOD). 
  However, in other browsers, this works just like `<img
  src='image.jpg' alt='image'>`.

### EDIT

I don't have a fixed container width.  It changes with the size of the window and the sizes of adjacent elements.

Comment: There’s a missing `'` character before `max-width`. Do you have this error in your code as well or just in your post?

Comment: the missing `'` is just in the post.  fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example:

```
div#div_img img{
    max-width:400px;  //Cointainers width
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a fixed container width. It changes with the size of the window and the sizes of adjacent elements.